# iFrame base64 not displaying on Chrome on android

Tags: reactjs, iframe, frontend, base64

[iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB0AB.jpg)

I am using React and my code looks something like this:

```
const content = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2UvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvWE9iamVjdDw8L0ltMCAyIDAgUj4+L1Byb2NTZXQgMyAwIFI+Pi9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAgNTAwIDMxNl0vQ3JvcEJveFswIDAgNTAwIDMxNl0vQ29udGVudHMgNC0ASWq+D72r3zqBATLvfTDgiIq8YzkyakeL04y4z8FlmBc0YQEJueG3D71ihZIWyE6lR6oYgRbEdJY4fa3gLhNamTlJ....."
 const iFrameSource =
    content + '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=Fit/preview'
<iframe className={someClass} src={iFrameSource} />
```